# how to call python functions defined in another .py file without interactive mode

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote two scripts: modbus_master.py and modbus_helpers.py.

modbus_helpers.py is just a bunch of raw functions I defined that I'm trying to call from modbus_master.py.

When I try to execute 'modbus_master.py' from the windows CLI this happens...

```
C:\Python27\modbus_simulator>modbus_master.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\modbus_master.py", line 3, in <module>
import modbus_helpers
ImportError: No module named modbus_helpers
```

However,
If I go to python interactive mode and do this...

```
C:\Python27\modbus_simulator>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)  on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import modbus_master
```

The code in modbus_master.py that calls modbus_helpers.py works just fine. So how do I bridge this gap here so that I can just do this and run the script without error?

C:\Python27\modbus_simulator>modbus_master.py

Code in modbus_master.py:

```
import sys
import json
import modbus_helpers
import os

def printRegsets():
    print 'these register sets were piped in...\r\n'
    regsetIndex = 0
    for regset in registersetsList:
        print str(regsetIndex) , ':', regset['Name']
        regsetIndex = regsetIndex + 1

path = os.path.normpath('C:\Python27\modbus_simulator\export2.txt')
registersetsList = modbus_helpers.getRegisterSetFromACMExportFile(path)
printRegsets()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. There was nothing wrong with the code. I missed the obvious...modbus_master.py must be in the same folder/directory as modbus_helpers.py for the 'import' statement to work.